# Recursion in Python: what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, recursion, simulation, vpython

I'm writing my first program in python and it has to simulate the mixing of particles (two gases). I don't know what am I doing wrong with this function.
I don't want the particles to leave certain area, that is the walls of container.
I use VPython.

```
def poruszanie(lista,pozycja,numCell):
    flaga = 0
    pozycjaTmp = (pozycja[0]+choice([-1,0,1]),pozycja[1]+choice([-1,0,1]),0)
    for i in range( 0, len(lista) ):
        if pozycjaTmp==lista[i].pos:
            flaga=1

    if flaga==1:
        return poruszanie(lista,(pozycja[0]+choice([-1,0,1]),pozycja[1]+choice([-1,0,1]),0),numCell)
    elif pozycjaTmp[0]==0 or pozycjaTmp[0]==numCell or pozycjaTmp[0]==-numCell or pozycjaTmp[1]==numCell or pozycjaTmp[1]==-numCell:
        return poruszanie(lista,(pozycja[0]+choice([-1,0,1]),pozycja[1]+choice([-1,0,1]),0),numCell)

    return pozycjaTmp
```

poruszanie - name of function

pozycja - position of the sphere

0,numCell,-numCell - the borders of container (0 is the wall in the middle that separate the gasses in the beggining)

All of this is in the x,y  plane and z is always 0
That's where I start to use this function:

```
while 1:
        rate(20)
        for i in range(0,len(self.listBalls)):
            self.listBalls[i].pos=poruszanie(self.listBalls,self.listBalls[i].pos,self.numCell)
```

Comment: I've edited your question to *hopefully* address an indentation error.  It would be helpful if you could state what error you're getting when you run this (if it throws an exception, post the entire traceback) as well as sample input and expected output (if possible)

Comment: It is suppose to make a change in position of a particle and it does. But it goes off the borders of the container

Comment: while 1:
rate(20)
for i in range(0,len(self.listBalls)):
                self.listBalls[i].pos=poruszanie(self.listBalls,self.listBalls[i].pos,self.numCell)

Answer (score 2):

I think you're calling it exactly the same each time and not returning properly:

```
if flaga==1:
    return poruszanie(lista,(pozycja[0]+choice([-1,0,1]),pozycja[1]+choice([-1,0,1]),0),numCell)
else:
    if pozycjaTmp[0]==0 or pozycjaTmp[0]==numCell or pozycjaTmp[0]==-numCell:
        poruszanie(lista,(pozycja[0]+choice([-1,0,1]),pozycja[1]+choice([-1,0,1]),0),numCell)
    elif pozycjaTmp[1]==numCell or pozycjaTmp[1]==-numCell:
        poruszanie(lista,(pozycja[0]+choice([-1,0,1]),pozycja[1]+choice([-1,0,1]),0),numCell)
```

From the first call you return, but from the next two, you don't. Also, the parameters you're passing look to be exactly the same.

**Edit**

Considering the edit and your new error (maximum depth reached).

That error means that your function is recursing farther than python allows.

I'm still not sure what you're doing but you need a base condition at which point no matter what the recursion will stop. If you're satisfying either branch of the `if ... elif ...` statement each time you call the function, your recursion will never stop. You need something that will always break, and preferably you should place it before the `if .. elif ...` block.

Comment: i've changed the post so you can see, how it look s now. There still is a problem

Comment: the particles look like they stay inside the container, but after a moment one by one they leave the borders